# Sql isolation levels, Read and Write locks

Tags: sql, transactions, isolation-level

A bit lame question but I got confused... 
Difference between isolation levels as far as I understood is how they managed their locks (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)). So as mentioned in the article there are Read, Write and Range locks but there is no definition what they are itself.
What are you allowed to do and what not. When I googled for it there was nothing concrete
and instead I got confused with new terms like Pessimistic Lock an Optimistic Lock, Exclusive lock, Gap lock and so on. I'd be pleased if someone give me a short overview and maybe point me a good bunch materials to enlighten myself.

My initial question which started the research of isolation levels was:

What happens when I have concurrent inserts (different users of web app) into one table when my transactions isolation level is READ_COMMITED. Is the whole table locked or not?
Or generally what happens down there :) ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: just to be complete:do you ask this for a specific RDBMS?

Comment: No I hoped it is generic concept ... No concrete RDBMS involved.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is what I was looking for ...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_locking

Comment: Are you sure this answers your question? It seems to be unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

> What happens when I have concurrent inserts (different users of web
>   app) into one table when my transactions isolation level is
>   READ_COMMITED.

"Read committed" means that other sessions cannot see the newly inserted row until its transaction is committed.  A SQL statement that runs without an explicit transaction is wrapped in an implicit one, so "read committed" affects all inserts.

Some databases implement "read committed" with locks.  For example, a read lock can be placed on the inserted row, preventing other tractions from reading it.  Other databases, like Oracle, use [multiversion concurrency control](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/consist.htm).  That means they can represent a version of the database before the insert.  This allows them to implement "read committed" without locks.

Comment: Could you go in more details for the different lock types - read, write and range ?

Answer (score 0):

With my understanding, isolation level will decide how and when the locks are to be acquired and released. 
[image]

Ref: http://aboutsqlserver.com/2011/04/28/locking-in-microsoft-sql-server-part-2-locks-and-transaction-isolation-levels/